# Why can these be declared as integers?

Tags: c, variables, int, fixed-point

In a program that seems to work well I have the following declarations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "system.h"

signed char input[4]; /* The 4 most recent input values */

char get_q7( void );
void put_q7( char );
void firFixed(signed char input[4]);

const int c0 = (0.0299 * 128 + 0.5); /* Converting from float to Q7 is multiplying by 2^n i.e. 128 = 2^7 since we use Q7 and round to the nearest integer*/
const int c1 = (0.4701 * 128 + 0.5);
const int c2 = (0.4701 * 128 + 0.5);
const int c3 = (0.0299 * 128 + 0.5);
const int half = (0.5000 * 128 + 0.5);

enum { Q7_BITS = 7 };

void firFixed(signed char input[4])
{
    int sum = c0*input[0] + c1*input[1] + c2*input[2] + c3*input[3];
    signed char output = (signed char)((sum + half) >> Q7_BITS);
    put_q7(output);
}

int main(void)
{   
    int a;
    while(1)
    {    
     for (a = 3 ; a > 0 ; a--)
    {
      input[a] = input[a-1];
    }      
     input[0]=get_q7();           
     firFixed(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't understand how it's possibl to declare a fractional number as `int` which is done with the constants. It's supposed to be Q7 notation but why is it done this way and how can the compiler accept an int that is a fractional number? Will it simply take the integer part of the fraction and if so why isn't a cast required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a floating point value is converted to an integer, it's *truncated*. That means that all digits after the decimal point is simply removed. E.g. `12.34` becomes `12`, and `12.99` *also* becomes `12`. There is no rounding done.

That is what the `+ 0.5` part does in the initializations. It's simply a way to convert a floating point value to integer with rounding. For example, `0.0299 * 128` is `3.8272` which truncated would be `3`. But with the `+ 0.5` it's `4.3272` which truncated becomes `4`, which is the rounded value of `3.8272`.

There may however still be problems, and you might want to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Cast required only in case of **type promotion** not in case of **type truncation**.